# Compute average (with condition) in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

**Wanted Result**: Average of the turnover value on days that are between the start and end reference period.

Using Tableau Desktop 
Lod expression

The first step is i return the turnover value on days that are between the start and end reference period, and return null otherwise.

**Daily Turnover in reference period**

```
IF  [Date]>= [Start reference date] 
and [Date]<= [End reference date] 
THEN [Amount] END
```

Second Step is to calculate the average across this range of values for each product.

**Average Turnover in reference period**

```
{FIXED [Product]: AVG(Daily Turnover in reference period)}
```

Here a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwaK2.png)

The average must be 2331 and not 24.

Really i need HELP.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your data look like. You have a Date, Product and Amount field. Do you have one data row per date per product? Or several? In any case, gist of your problem is that your LOD does not reference your Date field

Comment: Thanks, I have several rows per Date per Product.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible approaches, here is one.

Define an LOD calc as **Daily_Amount_Per_Product**

```
{ FIXED Product, Date : SUM([Amount]) }
```

Put **Date** on the filter shelf and select the range of dates you want to analyze. Put **Product** on the Rows shelf and put **Daily_Amount_Per_Product** on the Columns shelf.

At this point you are almost, but not quite done. Since your LOD calc as at a deeper level of detail (has more dimensions in play) than your view, Tableau will perform aggregation to get a result at the same level as your view - which is why you see the word SUM before your field on the Columns shelf. If you want to see the average instead of the sum, change SUM to AVG and you should have your result.